# Find the solutions set for a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Let

$$\left\{ {\matrix{
   {a_1x + b_1y + c_1z = d_1}  \cr 
   {a_2x + b_2y + c_2z = d_2}  \cr 
   {a_3x + b_3y + c_3z = d_3}  \cr 
 } } \right.$$

It's given that the unique solution for the system is $(2,-1,0)^T$.

Find the solutions set for the following linear system:

$$\left\{ {\matrix{
   {d_1x + b_1y + c_1z = a_1}  \cr 
   {d_2x + b_2y + c_2z = a_2}  \cr 
   {d_3x + b_3y + c_3z = a_3}  \cr 
 } } \right.$$

Well, since the original system has a unique solution, I can infer all the stuff which are true for this kind ($\det(A)\ne 0$, $Ax=0$ has the trivial solution, $A$ is invertible, etc..)

I couldn't make the connection though, to the desired system.
What's the trick here?

**Update:**
Maybe subtracting the desired system's rows from the original system's row?

Comment: I hope you are not intending to eliminate the person in your icon - he is much too important for that ;-)

Comment: Haha, good one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it this way

you have solved

$$\left\{ {\matrix{
   {a_1x + b_1y + c_1z + d_1 w=0}  \cr 
   {a_2x + b_2y + c_2z + d_2 w=0}  \cr 
   {a_3x + b_3y + c_3z + d_3 w=0}  \cr 
 } } \right.
$$
and the solution is $(-2a,a,0,a)$ setting $a=-1$, makes the coefficients for the $d$'s into $-1$ and gives the original solution.

now you want so solve
$$\left\{ {\matrix{
   {-a_1 + b_1y + c_1z + d_1 w=0}  \cr 
   {-a_2 + b_2y + c_2z +  d_2 w=0}  \cr 
   {-a_3 + b_3y + c_3z +  d_3 w=0}  \cr 
 } } \right.
$$

Here we want to chose $a$ so that the coefficient if the $a_i$'s is $-1$
 that is $-2a=-1$ so $a=\frac{1}{2}$ and this gives the solution

$(-1,\frac{1}{2},0,\frac{1}{2})$

So noting the rearrangement of the variables equation as given in the question we would have
$x=\frac{1}{2}, y=\frac{1}{2}, z=0$

Comment: I can see you turned the system equation to the form of $Ax=0$ with $4$ variables where the coefficients of $w$ are the $b$'s of the original system equation. How can you conclude immediately the solutions set is $(2a,-a,0,a)$? I'm probably missing something very fundamental here.

Comment: No your confusing me,...the solution to a homogenous system depends on a arbitrary constant.

Comment: Can you help me solve the second system? The signs are the same for $y,z$ but inverse for $x, w$. So...

Comment: I have edited my answer I hope it answers your question. Thanks for accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  From the given information, can you find all solutions of the following system?
$$\left\{ {\matrix{
   {a_1x + b_1y + c_1z + d_1w = 0}  \cr 
   {a_2x + b_2y + c_2z + d_2w = 0}  \cr 
   {a_3x + b_3y + c_3z + d_3w = 0}  \cr 
 } } \right.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let 
$$
A_1 = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
d_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\
d_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\
d_3 & b_3 & c_3 \end{array} \right) \\
A_2 = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a_1 & d_1  & c_1 \\
a_2 & d_2  & c_2 \\
a_3 & d_3  & c_3 \end{array} \right) \\
A_3 = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a_1 & b_1 & d_1 \\
a_2 & b_2 & d_2 \\
a_3 & b_3 & d_3 \end{array} \right) \\
$$
Using Cramer's rule, we can say that,
$$
\frac{\det(A_1)}{\det(A)} = 2,\frac{\det(A_2)}{\det(A)} = -1,\frac{\det(A_3)}{\det(A)} = 0
$$

For the second system the solutions are 
$$
\frac{\det(A)}{\det(A_1)} = \frac{1}{2},-\frac{\det(A_2)}{\det(A_1)} = \frac{1}{2},-\frac{\det(A_3)}{\det(A_1)} = 0
$$
Remember that when we interchange two columns in a matrix, the sign of its determinant changes.